# nsISelectionDisplay custom highlight controller? (related to nsISelectionController)

Tags: firefox-addon, selection

I made an addon HiliteOnSelection, when hilight something it uses the `SELECTION_FIND` context to highlight other instances. The issue with this is that highlight all feature of find bar uses same controller.

http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/content/base/public/nsISelectionController.idl#30

Can you please help me to figure out how to create my custom highlight controller and how to style it, the SELECTION_FIND is pink.

This is how i get the selection_find context/controller and highlight with it:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/files/browse/247620/file/bootstrap.js#L147

```
let findSelection = controller.getSelection(Ci.nsISelectionController.SELECTION_FIND);
    findSelection.addRange(aRange);
```

Comment: Quicksaver appears to have accomplished this task ( see https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/findbar-tweak/?src=search -- option to change color is in add-on preferences, accessible in ctrl-shift-A list).  I haven't yet looked at their source code.

Comment: Superb man! Thanks I looked into it I couldn't figure it out, please help when you get a chance. I'm working on another addon right now so can't focus on this but will definitely be needing this in future. Much thanks for it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this reply from the addon author. He's a nice guy:

> Hey Noitidart,
>
> You might find this one helpful:
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsISelectionController
>
> I'm hardly the master you think I am, actually. :) To change those
>   colors I just change the values for preferences:
>
> ui.textHighlightBackground ui.textHighlightForeground
>   ui.textSelectBackgroundAttention -> SELECTION_ATTENTION, it's not a
>   highlight, it's a normal selection (as you would select some text with
>   your mouse and it would turn the regular blue blackground, in windows
>   at least) but it's given "attention", so it has the green background
>   that the find operation reports. Basically it's a way of showing the
>   user "Here I am!!" after firefox automatically selecs the text he
>   searched for.
>
> And I really don't know most of those contants, SELECTION_NORMAL is
>   for normal text selection, like it would be when you select text with
>   your mouse, SELECTION_FIND is for the highlights, and I only know the
>   ON/HIDDEN/OFF/DISABLED ones which are self-explanatory.
>   SELECTION_SPELLCHECK is probably for the auto-correct when you are
>   typing in an editable content node, but I'm just guessing that one
>   from the name.
>
> Also, as far as I know, it's not possible to just create custom
>   selection ranges/contants, as the code simply won't recognize them
>   without editing the C++ code as well. Which is actually one of the
>   reasons I haven't implemented
>   https://github.com/Quicksaver/FindBar-Tweak/issues/76 yet.
>
> Hope any of this helps. I'm sorry to disappoint on the custom
>   controller thing.
>
> Luís Miguel

So he changes the colors with a simple pref change. I'm going to have to dig into how that pref changes it.

He also thinks its not possible to create custom controllers without C++, I hope this is not true I'll keep digging if anyone can help that would be great.